# Changing the Editor PIDA IDE uses

Tags: python

I recently tried the PIDA IDE, and when starting up I selected vim, I now want to use emacs, but there is no option so I tried reinstalling, purging and nothing has worked...

How can I change the editor PIDA uses?

Comment: Most programs will put configuration in a hidden file in your home folder - look for `.pida` or `.config/pida`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a folder called `.pida2` in the home directory. Inside it is a file called `first_run_wizard`, which contains this:

```
#Remove this to rerun the start wizard
```

So, just delete this file using a file manager or the command `rm ~/.pida2/first_run_wizard`.

Now, when you start PIDA, the first run wizard runs and allows you to pick an editor.